# Why is this solution to $2\sin^2(x) + \sin(x) - 1 = 0$ incorrect?

Tags: trigonometry

$$2\sin^2(x) + \sin(x) - 1 = 0$$

$$\sin(x) = \cos (2x)$$

$$ \sin(x) = \sin (2x  + \dfrac{1}{2} \pi)$$

$$ x = -\dfrac{1}{2}\pi - k \cdot 2\pi$$ or $$ x = \dfrac{1}{6} \pi + k \cdot \dfrac{2}{3} \pi$$

Why is this incorrect?

Comment: $x = \pi - (2x + \dfrac{1}{6} \pi) + k \cdot 2\pi$

Comment: What invites trouble here is that $\sin x$ has a period of $2\pi$, while $\sin(2x + \frac{\pi}{2})$ has a period of $\pi$, so direct comparison is not reliable.  Keep in mind, as Fourier's comment also indicates, that $\sin x = \sin(\pi - x)$ [the sine of an angle is equal to the sine of the supplementary angle].  So $\sin \alpha = \sin \beta$ implies $\alpha = \beta$ _or_ $\alpha = \pi - \beta$.

Comment: how did you get from $(-1/2pi-2kpi)$ to $(1/6pi+(2/3)kpi)$?

Answer (score 2):

Recall that
$$\sin(A) = \sin(B) \implies A = n \pi +(-1)^n B$$
Also, you could solve your problem in a slightly easier way. Note that
$$2 \sin^2(x) + \sin(x) - 1 = (2 \sin(x)-1)(\sin(x)+1) = 0 \implies \sin(x) = \dfrac12 \text{ or }-1$$
Hence,
$$x = n \pi +(-1)^n \dfrac{\pi}6, 2n \pi - \dfrac{\pi}2$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sin y=\sin x$ iff $\sin y-\sin x=0$ iff $$\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}(y-x)\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}(y+x)\right)=0$$ iff 
$\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}(y-x)\right)=0$ or $\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}(y+x)\right)=0$ iff $y-x=2n\pi$ or $y+x=2(\pi/2+n\pi)$ iff
$y=x+2n\pi$ or $y=\pi-x+2n\pi$. From here, you should get your answer. When I work this out, your answer is actually correct.

An easier way is to factor and solve $\sin x=1/2$ and $\sin x=-1$. That way, you get
$x=-(1/2)\pi+2n\pi$ or $x=\pi/6+2n\pi$ or $x=5\pi/6+2n\pi$ for the answer. But this answer is equivalent to the above answer.