# How do you get to this step?

Tags: trigonometry

I was looking at a [question on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365830/why-is-this-incorrect), and wonder as to why this is wrong: $2\sin^2(x)+\sin(x)−1=0$

$\sin(x)=\cos(2x)$

$\sin(x)=\sin(2x+1/2π)$

$x=−1/2π−k⋅2π$

or

$x=1/6π+k⋅23π$

I do not understand how the poster got from $(−1/2\pi−2k \pi )$ to $(1/6\pi+(2/3)k\pi)$. It looks like he factored out a -1/3, but I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Could you include a link to the post in question?

Comment: Sure, this is the link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365830/why-is-this-incorrect

Comment: Thanks for responding promptly. I added a link to the question in your post.

Comment: Ok no problem and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you really need to write $\pi/2$, not $1/2\pi$! Offhand, it seems you want $\cos y = \sin(\pi/2-y)$.